# htaccess eating up session variables?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with rewrite rule, it seems like it "eats" my set session variables.
Here's the contents of htaccess

```
AddHandler phpini-cgi .php
Action phpini-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-custom-ini.cgi

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

It seems that whenever I store session vars, they are not there when I click between pages.
Any idea in my code above, what causes that and how to modify so it works?

Comment: are you sure it is your htaccess that does this? You do call all sorts of `session_start` in each script, don't you?

Comment: To clarify: sessions work fine if you disable URL rewriting?

Answer (score 3):

If you are appending a session ID to the URL, you can add the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So it wont remove any GET variables.

Comment: +1 I don't know/care whether that's the actual problem—it's a nice catch anyway.

Comment: when I rename htaccess, the session problem goes away so it must be. I will ad the QSA yes, thanks for that.

Comment: anybody else? it's almost like the session path is not "correct"

Comment: @MichelWouterse - Please read about [how sessions work](http://es.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) and verify the steps in order: Is the ID being transmitted? Does the ID change? Is the file being created? ...